# Camera.open() occur error (using MediaRecorder)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

My action flow:

1. Camera.Open()
2. Camera.unlock()
3. recorder = new MediaRecorder();
4. recorder.setCamera(), and then.. more setting.

(click start button)

5. recorder.start()

(click stop button)

6. recorder.stop()
7. recorder.release()
8. recorder = null;

(save recorded video file)

9. Camera.Open() <= Occur error

step 9 is for recording again more video.

But, This step occur Error.

It's logcat :
[image]

It's My source :

---

public class Talk extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

```
Context context;


SurfaceView sfv_Preview;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
Camera camera;

boolean recording = false;

private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "/sdcard/Vitalk/temp.mp4";
private static final String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "temp.mp4";
private static final int RECORDING_TIME = 10000;

//Uri fileUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_talk);


    File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/Vitalk/");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();

    sfv_Preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.sfv_Preview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    holder = sfv_Preview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);



    initRecorder();



    context = this;


    ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibt_Record)).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
                sfv_Preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recorder.start();
                recording = true;
                Log.d("recod", "click start");
            }
            else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction() || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                Log.d("recod", "click stop");
                if (recording) {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recording = false;
                    recorder.release();
                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

                    uploadFile(OUTPUT_FILE);


                    recorder = null;

                    initRecorder();
                    prepareRecorder();



                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prepareRecorder();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private void initRecorder() {

    Camera camera = Camera.open(1);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    camera.unlock();


    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setCamera(camera);

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));


    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(RECORDING_TIME);
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(10485760); // Approximately 5 megabytes
}

private void prepareRecorder() {
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    recorder.setOrientationHint(90);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        //finish();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //finish();
    }
}

public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null; 
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);


     try {

           // open a URL connection to the Servlet
         FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
         URL url = new URL("http://133.130.117.56/visualtalk/func/FileUpload.php");

         // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
         conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
         conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

         dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                 + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

         // create a buffer of  maximum size
         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

         while (bytesRead > 0) {

           dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
           bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
           bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
           bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

          }

         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

         // Responses from the server (code and message)
         int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
         String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

         Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                 + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

         if(serverResponseCode == 200){


         }   

         //close the streams //
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();



    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                         + e.getMessage(), e); 
    }
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void run() {

                sfv_Preview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
 }
```

}

What is problem?..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use `camera.release()` before the next `open()`